# Typescript hide props from super class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class that extends another class. For example:

```
class Store extends BehaviorSubject {
  constructor(obj) {
     super(obj)
  }
}
```

I also have more classes the extends `Store`. 
What I need is a way to hide some properties from the `BehaviorSubject` superclass, for example, the `next()` method.

```
class SomeStore extends Store {

}

// I want to hide from this class some methods, properties
// That exists on the BehaviorSubject class. 
const s = new SomeStore();
```

There is a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, I want only the Store to know about this props.

Comment: There's no nice way to "hide" those properties. And I strongly recommend reconsider the approach. It's better to not inherit at all from the `Store` directly, but instead wrap into a specially designed class which does not expose `Store`'s `next()` and everything else you want to keep hidden.

Comment: @Igor Can you give an example, please?

Comment: I know you've already accepted another answer, but you can take a look at my variant of the code if you like.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. You can override the method in the subclass to do something else (or nothing) but this is violating the Liskov Substitution principle.

If your Store class is not a BehaviorSubject, and does not act like one, then extending is not correct. A Store should contain a private instance of BehaviorSubject in this case, and if necessary expose some of its methods/properties, by “proxying” them.

Comment: Yup, glad I'm not alone thinking this way.

Comment: Take a look at my answer below and let me know if I can clean it up for the OP. Hopefully, it's aligned with your vision of "proxying" the methods (I tried to do it quite literally) :).

Answer (score 3):

You can write something like the code below. There's also no inheritance, which is good. Passing the `Store` object via constructor is a way to implement [DIP (dependency inversion principle)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle). It's good on its own, because it decouples classes and also makes `StoreWrapper` testable.

**Code**

```
export class StoreWrapper {

  constructor(private _store: Store) { }

  // Expose things that you think are okay to expose...
  getValue = this._store.getValue;
  onCompleted = this._store.onCompleted;
  onError = this._store.onError;
  onNext = this._store.onNext;

  // Anything that is not exposed similar to how it is done above, will be hidden
  // next = this._store.next;

}
```

**Usage**

```
const originalStore = ...; // <--- this is your original `Store` object.

const wrappedStore = new StoreWrapper(originalStore);
const value = wrappedStore.getValue();
// ... and so on
```

**Important Notes**:

- While `this._store.next()` is still possible to invoke from within the `StoreWrapper`, this code is not violating the [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). In other words, it does not break the way inheritance is supposed to be used.
- You can now test this `StoreWrapper` class very easily, in case it grows and gets some "meat" (logic).

Comment: Exactly my thoughts!