# Private inheritance equivalent in Typescript (Only including or excluding specific class members or properties)

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance, visual-studio-code, typescript-generics

What is the best way to simulate private inheritance in Typescript? Specifically, the chid class wants to hide certain members of a parent class.

For example, the expected workaround should achieve the following:

Class `CustomArray<T>` extends from `Array<T>`, and hides specific members say `pop()` and `shift()` only.

```
let c1 = new CustomArray<number>();
c1.push(10, 20, 30, 40, 50); // okay
c1.shift(); // should error
c1.pop();   // should error
c1.sort(); // okay  etc...
```

Here is what I tried, but vscode still allowed the supposed to be restricted members.

```
//Try to hide pop() and push():
type T1<T> = Exclude<Array<T>, 'pop'| 'push'>

// check
let x: T1<number> = [];
x.push(3);  // allowed -- okay
x.pop();    // also allowed -- but wanted it to be an error
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript hide props from super class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936723/typescript-hide-props-from-super-class)

Comment: @DerekBrown while it might be close to a duplicate, the provided answers are old and irrelevant. However, the answer to this question below solves the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to use inheritance because you don't intend to allow a `CustomArray<T>` to be used in all the same ways an `Array<T>` can be used.

What you can do is define your new type as a function of `Array<T>` and make the `CustomArray` constructor the same as the `Array` constructor at runtime:

```
type CustomArray<T> = Pick<Array<T>, Exclude<keyof Array<T>, "shift" | "pop">>;
const CustomArray: new <T>() => CustomArray<T> = Array;

let c1 = new CustomArray<number>();
c1.push(10, 20, 30, 40, 50); // okay
c1.shift(); // error
c1.pop();   // error
c1.sort(); // okay
```

That works the way you asked.  But keep in mind that this is a "shallow" transformation of `Array<T>`.  For example, the `sort()` method will still return `Array<T>`, not `CustomArray<T>`:

```
c1.sort().pop(); // okay
```

If you really want a "deep" transformation where all relevant mentions of `Array<T>` get replaced with `CustomArray<T>`, you might need to go ahead and manually specify the full interface, as an automatic mapping is unlikely to work the way you want:

```
interface CustomArray<T> {
  length: number;
  toString(): string;
  toLocaleString(): string;
  // pop(): T | undefined;
  push(...items: T[]): number;
  concat(...items: ConcatArray<T>[]): CustomArray<T>;
  concat(...items: (T | ConcatArray<T>)[]): CustomArray<T>;
  join(separator?: string): string;
  reverse(): CustomArray<T>;
  // shift(): T | undefined;
  slice(start?: number, end?: number): CustomArray<T>;
  sort(compareFn?: (a: T, b: T) => number): this;
  // ... ALL the other methods, omitted for brevity
} 
const CustomArray: new <T>() => CustomArray<T> = Array;
const c1 = new CustomArray();
c1.push(10, 20, 30, 40, 50); // okay
c1.shift(); // error
c1.pop();   // error
c1.sort(); // okay  
c1.sort().pop(); // error
```

That is more tedious but you can exercise a lot more control over the result.  Either way should work for you, though.  Hope that helps; good luck!